# Display a CLI within my GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-interface, command-line-interface

I want to make a program show the console output of a running CLI program, i.e. Minecraft server. But within a gui. So buttons and stuff for configuration of the server and then a console on one side to display server side events.

To clarify. I'm not wanting someone to tell me how to talk to the server. I'm wanting help with the gui code.

Comment: seeing code for the data structure would help a lot. as it would give clues to the best controls to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options I see here:

- You could have the CLI visible and control its position; with a hole cut in the region of your form to fit in the CLI. This might work well without a lot of work.
- Or you could make the CLI run invisibly and capture its output and also its error output and display them in a TextBox. This is a bit harder, especially if you also want to send commands. To do this you would probably use a 2nd textbox as an input area.

I have done something similar and you may want to have alook at some of my code in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289288/how-can-i-feed-commands-to-cmd-exe-process-via-an-input-stream-manually) to my own question.

The challenge in version 2 is to keep the input and output stream in synch and running.