# Multiple CMD commands during same Process

Tags: c#, cmd

Alright, first some background information. I've written an application to have a real-time connection with the cmd.exe

**The problem:**
Instead of writing once to a Process, I want to write multiple times without closing the cmd.exe. This causes an error because I have to close the StreamWriter before being able to retrieve any output and after I've recieved output, I want to write to it again.

**Example:** 
I want to give a command `cd C:\` and recieve the output with the changed path. After that I want to see which files are inside the C:\ directory by using `dir`. 
I don't want the process to restart, because it resets the path.

I know I can simply use `dir C:\`, but that's not the point.
This is only a brief example, I want to use this for many other things that require this problem to be solved.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            pInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            pInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            pInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            pInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = pInfo;

            bool pStarted = false;

            Console.Write("Command: ");
            string command = Console.ReadLine();

            while (command != "exit")
            {
                if (!pStarted && command == "start")
                {
                    p.Start();
                    Console.WriteLine("Process started.");

                    pStarted = true;
                }
                else if (pStarted)
                {
                    StreamWriter sWriter = p.StandardInput;
                    if (sWriter.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                    {
                        sWriter.WriteLine(command);
                    }
                    sWriter.Close();

                    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                    string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + output + "\n");
                }

                Console.Write("\nCommand: ");
                command = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Process terminated.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            }
    }
```

Does anyone know how I can hold on to a process and write multiple times to it, each time recieving the output.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit :** This might or might not be slightly identical to the following question : [Execute multiple command lines with the same process using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437419/execute-multiple-command-lines-with-the-same-process-using-net). The question linked has no useful answer and is diffrent in multiple ways. One huge problem I'm facing is that I want the output printed after every command the user sends.

Comment: "have to close the StreamWriter " - why? [Standard way to communicating to CMD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results) using events (or separate thread to read/write) should work fine (assuming you are showing very simplified code)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute multiple command lines with the same process using .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437419/execute-multiple-command-lines-with-the-same-process-using-net)

Comment: @EmpereurAiman The linked question has no answer.

Comment: @EmpereurAiman My main problem is that I'm looking to print out the output from my cmd after every command the user sends.

Comment: But you can read multiple times as well as write multiple times.

Comment: @BugFinder That's what I'm trying... within the same process ofcourse. As soon as I send a second comment I recieve an error. Try to run my code and you'll see.

Comment: catching output when it happens may be done by hooking into the right events. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289288/how-can-i-feed-commands-to-cmd-exe-process-via-an-input-stream-manually?s=1|1.9373) for a (rather confusing) example.

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the stream and you can't simply create a new stream, so

1. declare `sWriter` outside the loop
2. don't close the stream

Unfortunately, you can then not use `ReadToEnd()` any more, since that would wait until the process terminates, which `cmd` doesn't. Therefore, you have to

3. read the console output asynchronously.

This again, results in problems with the output, since your output "Command:" may interfere with the output of `cmd`.

The following async version of your program should solve your basic problem, but will leave you with the mixed output:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace MultiConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                FileName = "cmd.exe"
            };

            var p = new Process {StartInfo = pInfo};

            bool pStarted = false;

            Console.Write("Command: ");
            string command = Console.ReadLine();
            StreamWriter sWriter = null;
            while (command != "exit")
            {
                if (!pStarted && command == "start")
                {
                    p.Start();
                    sWriter = p.StandardInput;
                    pStarted = true;
                    ConsumeConsoleOutput(p.StandardOutput);
                    Console.WriteLine("Process started.");
                }
                else if (pStarted)
                {
                    if (sWriter.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                    {
                        sWriter.WriteLine(command);
                    }
                }

                Console.Write("\nCommand: ");
                command = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            if (sWriter != null) sWriter.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Process terminated.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static async void ConsumeConsoleOutput(TextReader reader)
        {
            var buffer = new char[1024];
            int cch;

            while ((cch = await reader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                Console.Write(new string(buffer, 0, cch));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparantly the "async" namespace can not be used in VS2010, so I might need to install some libraries to get this working. But thank you very much! It should fix the problem.

Comment: @Shwasted: VS2010? Don't you want to use 2015 Community Edition? It has almost [as many features as 2013 Professional](http://superuser.com/questions/947923/upgrading-from-visual-studio-2013-professional-to-visual-studio-2015-community).

Comment: First of all, sorry for the late answer. When trying to run your code, I recieve an error : "'TextReader' does not contain a definition for 'ReadAsync' and no extension method 'ReadAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'TextReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" NOTE : I've included all libraries you're using and I'm using .NET FrameWork 4.5 so according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx it should be good...

Comment: @Shwasted: I also tried in VS2013 and set the the target framework to 4.5 - and it works. You just need 2 references: `System` and `System.Core`.

Comment: Problem solved... I'm apprantly an idiot, when transporting my VS2010 project to VS2015 I didn't change the framework to 4.5.